# pandas - Broadcasting division

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having two dataframes:

- `df_1` with single index `i` and one column `LB` of `float`s.
- `df_2` with multiindex `i, a, s` and 500 columns of `floats`s.

My goal is to divide each value in `df_1[LB]` by each cell of `df_2` with corresponding index `i` in order to outputing `df_3` with same dimension of `df_2`.

My old approach with iteration works for `df_2` with two levels multiindex but failed when i added the third level.

```py
df_3= pd.DataFrame(index=df_2.index, columns=df_2.columns)
for _i in i:
    df_3.loc[_i] = df_1.loc[_i][LB] / df_2.loc[_i] # TypeError: cannot align on a multi-index with out specifying the join levels
```

I wonder if there is a general broadcasting way?

Edit: I found a way to replicating values of `df_1` into `df_3` then divide `df_3` by `df_2`:

```py
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(index=df_2.index, columns=df_2.columns)
for _i in i:
    df_3.loc[_i] = df_1.loc[_i][LB]
df_3 = df_3 / df_2
```

But then if `df_1` also has multiindex (subset of `df_2`), what is the nicest way to propagating values of `df_1` to `df_3` without looping?

Comment: how your df_2 look like?

Comment: 3 level multiindex `i, a, s` and 500 columns. Each index level is an array of single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *broadcast* `df_1` to match the multi-level index of the second dataframe. Then you can easily broadcast the division at the numpy level:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df_1.values, len(df_2)/len(df_1)),
                   index = df_2.index, columns=df_1.columns)

df_3 = pd.DataFrame(df_2.values / tmp.values, index=df_2.index,
                   columns=df_2.columns)
```

The only requirements are:

- `df_1` must have one single column
- `df_2` must have either same index as `df1` or have a multi-index for which the first level is `df1.index`

---

In fact, it is enough to just reshape `df_2.values` and let numpy broadcast the operation:

```
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data=(
    df_2.values.reshape(len(df_1),(len(df_2) // len(df_1)) * len(df_2.columns))
    / df_1.values).reshape(len(df_2), len(df_2.columns)),
                    index=df_2.index, columns=df_2.columns)
```

Comment: I like the elegance of reshaping. However, there is a problem with the order of elements. One should `sort_index` before division in order to correctly matching the initial index.

Comment: @phet Indeed, I assumed that the first level was the same, including order...

Comment: I thought as well the orders were the same at both side. But the result seemed odd. I had to `sort_index` before applying your solution.